# Is there an Excel function (/method) for text approximate matching with properties of vlookup based on two columns?

Tags: excel, data-cleaning, fuzzy-search

Approximate string searching and matching using Excel.

I've been working on an excel problem.
The first table A3:B9 contains the following column names:

- country
- name
- id

My second table is A12:C19 with the Columns:

- adcounty
- adname
- ID

Excel problem:

[image]

What I need is to get the numbers of ID from the second table based on 2 columns’ information using this rule:
If the name from the first table approximately equals to the adname from the second table then check the equality of the corresponding country and assign the number of the matched adcountry and adname to the corresponding id to the first table.
The problem is in the approximate matching, because my data contains a lot of typos.
Is there a way to do this using excel functions?
Thank you.

Comment: You can do approximate match with `VLOOKUP`, but you need to sort the lookup table first in order to get correct results. You can't use two columns for lookup unless your lookup table has them merged in a single column.

Comment: Also it's not very clear what you need. Can you please edit your question, include copy-pastable data set and give us an example of what the result should like.

Comment: Kindly provide us with the sample data, then we'll easily be able to advise a solution or a formula to accomplish this.